# Ubuntu error: apt-aget update intel-mkl distribution error

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, intel-mkl

In Ubuntu, I am trying to run the command

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

but I get the error message

```
Get:18 https://apt.repos.intel.com/intelpython binary/ Packages [3.166 B]
It got 7.878 B in 2 s (3.717 B/s).            
Packet lists were read ...Ready
W: Conflict in distribution: https://apt.repos.intel.com/intelpython binary/ InRelease (binary/ expected, but  got)
W: Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/intel-mkl.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/intelpython.list:1
W: Target Translations (de_DE) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/intel-    mkl.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/intelpython.list:1
W: Target Translations (de) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/intel-mkl.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/intelpython.list:1
W: Target Translations (en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/intel-mkl.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/intelpython.list:1
```

What can I do to solve this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue maybe GPG key used to sign packages in apt channel has expired. The issue can be resolved by [updating the key](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installing-intel-free-libs-and-python-apt-repo).

Try again to reinstall the key and try the steps in https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installing-intel-free-libs-and-python-apt-repo

Comment: thanks but the issue remains. What else could I do?